# how can I embed an assembly into a console application without ILMerge?

Tags: c#, assemblies, console-application, assembly-resolution

There are a lot of posts on here about this, I'm using [this code from another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96732/embedding-one-dll-inside-another-as-an-embedded-resource-and-then-calling-it-from/97290#97290) and placing a delegate assignation in my Main() method. None of the other posts have directly answered my question.

I've got my third party assembly embedded as a resource but when I fire up the app:

- I'm getting a TypeInitializationException with an inner of FileNotFoundException. It's trying to find the assembly on the file system and failing.
- it's never getting to the Main method, where the event handler for AssemblyResolve is assigned

I have two assembly refs that are embedded in my Resources.resx, one is a third party tool (command line parser) and the other is a Library file where the meat of the application resides.

Maybe this isn't possible with a console app? Seems unlikely but I don't see a way around it.

**Re: ILMerge etc:** I'd like to get this done entirely in code without involving any tools. Reason: I don't want to have source code in the repository that requires other team members to install a tool that they probably don't have already. If that's not possible then ILMerge looks like the next best option.

Comment: How is ILMerge any less of a first party tool than C# and visual studio itself?

Comment: @Chris: good point. Editing now. Still, if I can get this done without involving ILMerge I'd prefer to do it that way. It seems reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using ILMerge to merge the assemlies into one rather than embedding as a resource. This is download site for [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en).

You would merge your third party assemblies into your console app.

Comment: Oops, beat me. I just added "I'd prefer not to use a 3rd party..."

Comment: guess I should have read the link to the other SO question :)

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it should be possible with just a few lines of code, I just can't figure out how to get the event to fire at the right time in the app's lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at application virtualization tools like [XenoCode](http://www.xenocode.com/). They can package multiple assemblies (including the .net framework itself) into a stand alone executable.

Answer (score 1):

If it is mixed mode assembly, it has to reside on the disk. Some limitation or something.