# Use the dll into a resources in a C# console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dllimport

I have a "Console Application" in C# that uses a external dll e.g.

```
[DllImport("utils\\rapi.dll")] 
internal static extern int CeRapiInit();
..
..
```

Then,  I need that this dll (radi.dll) is loaded from a resources into console application. How to do this?

Comment: What is you're actual question?

Comment: How i cann configurate my console application to these dll is taked from a resources into a application

Comment: this is so many times duplicated.. see these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523641/embed-a-dll-into-a-console-application http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418539/how-can-i-embed-an-assembly-into-a-console-application-without-ilmerge