# How do I specify my own bitmap image in a call to Commands2.AddNamedCommand2?

Tags: c#, .net, resources, visual-studio-addins

I'm writing a Visual Studio add-in and have a 16x16 bitmap resource that I would like to use as the button image for my menu item.

Following [these instructions from the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228771.aspx), I renamed the resource `1` and the file `1.bmp`, then edited `Resources.resx` accordingly:

```
<data name="1" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\1.bmp;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
</data>
```

I then changed my call to [`Commands2.AddNamedCommand2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.commands2.addnamedcommand2.aspx), passing `false` and `1` as the arguments for `MSOButton` and `Bitmap` respectively:

```
Command command = commands.AddNamedCommand2(addIn, "MyAddIn", "MyAddIn", "Open MyAddIn", false, 1, ref contextGUIDS,
                                            (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported + (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled, (int)vsCommandStyle.vsCommandStylePictAndText, vsCommandControlType.vsCommandControlTypeButton);
```

Now when I launch the add-in in Visual Studio, `Commands2.AddNamedCommand2` throws a `FileNotFoundException`:

> Additional information: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'MyAddIn.resources,
>   Version=0.1.3939.33205, Culture=en,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I'm doing this in Visual Studio 2005, in case that is significant.

**EDIT2:** The project is [on github](https://github.com/philbooth/VisualSO), if anyone wants to look at the source and/or try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: What happens if you restore `true, 59`? Have you added the resource file in the add-in-project? Do you have many resource files? Do you reference other projects?

Comment: If I restore `true, 59` the call succeeds and the smiley face icon is displayed. I have added the bitmap file as a resource in the add-in project. I do reference another project to display a user control on my tool window, although this problem persists when that code is commented out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create the resource-only assembly [manually](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2008/08/11/creating-resource-only-assemblies.aspx), e.g.

```
resgen.exe "Path\To\Resource.resx" "Path\To\Bin\en\MyAddin.resources"
al.exe /c:en /embed:"Path\To\Bin\en\MyAddin.resources" /out:"Path\To\Bin\en\MyAddin.resources.dll"
```

and then set your assembly version to 0.0.0.0 (or alternatively set the resource assembly version in the al.exe command, or use the `[assembly: System.Resources.SatelliteContractVersion()]` attribute), you should get past the FileNotFoundException. Using resgen.exe might also tell you why the assembly isn't being generated and linked automatically.

You can also subscribe to the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96732/embedding-one-dll-inside-another-as-an-embedded-resource-and-then-calling-it-from/97290#97290), to trace or override the loading of resource (or other) assemblies.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm still getting the `FileNotFoundException` though. The project is on github, in case looking at it will help: https://github.com/philbooth/VisualSO

Comment: Create a directory under Bin called 'en' and try the following post build:

"$(VS80COMNTOOLS)..\..\SDK\v2.0\Bin\resgen.exe" "$(ProjectDir)Properties\Resources.resx" "$(TargetDir)VisualSO.resources"
"$(WINDIR)\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\al.exe" /c:en /embed:"$(TargetDir)VisualSO.resources" /out:"$(TargetDir)\en\VisualSO.resources.dll" /v:0.1.0.0 /productv:0.1.0.0

Comment: Success! You are my hero. A legend. +100 :)

Comment: I have an open source project that took the easy way out and specified an MSO icon ordinal.  I could really use a little bit of help from a volunteer to refactor this into a proper icon if anyone would be willing to help me.  Thanks! :)