# parsing json in C# with json.net requires the json.net .dll?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a simple c# library (myLib.dll) that can be registered to applications. It can be used as a plug-in. Now i would like to use the json.net library from Newton King, but i do not want to have 2 .dll that i have to send around.

Is there a way to use json.net and somehow embed the .dll into myLib.dll that in the end i have only my .dll?

Edit: to clerify: Is it allowed to merge the jsonNET.dll with my own myLib.dll so that only myLib.dll will be visible as a file?

ok it has the MIT License: http://json.codeplex.com/license

Comment: check this thread... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96732/embedding-one-dll-inside-another-as-an-embedded-resource-and-then-calling-it-fro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can merge the libraries together using ilmerge.

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx

Make sure to carefully read the licence of any libraries you are merging in, as it may affect the distribution rules for your library. Also any application that uses your library will also have access to any merged libraries.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this remarkably easily using [Netz](http://madebits.com/netz/), a .net NET Executables Compressor & Packer.

Finally, as a few have already mentioned, [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx) may be another option to consider, albeit somewhat more involved.

Comment: Hm, .Netz claims to be open source, but it isn't. "You can use .NETZ out of the box free of charge and without any reference to its origin or author. .NETZ is an open source tool. You can modify its source code to fit your own needs, but you are not allowed to distribute your changes, or sell .NETZ modified versions."