# How to link external dll with my setup exe project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, dll, executable

I need to create a `stand alone EXE` of a solution. This solution contains `two` projects i.e:

- A-project (set up as start)
- B-project (A web services)

  B-project uses a external `DLL` which is reside on same `B-project` folder.
  Above solution runs perfectly after building it. Now i want to create a stand alone `EXE`. So that i can sell my product for commercial use (in my school).

To do this i have performed following points:

- Add a new project(`SETUP Project`) in the solution with `test` name.
- Now add `project output` and choose `A-project` from the `project` drop down.
- Then i do the same for the `B-project` i.e. Add `project output` and choose `B-project` from the `project` drop down.
- Check the `.net framework 4` dependencies which was fine.
- Build it.
- Install it.

I went to the my `program files` directory and run `test.exe` with run as administrator, and try to open the web services `URL`.

I got to know that `web services` runs perfectly but when i enter the url it returns me `Request error` which happens when the method written in `instance class` didn't execute perfectly. In my project the method written in `Instance class`called the externall `dll`.

How should i link that dll with my `EXE`. so that it runs perfectly fine?
Should i change the path in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deploy one .EXE:

- Add the dll that the Project B depend on as a Resource (right click on Add existing Item -> Select dll -> change build action to Embedded resources)
- Do the same with Project A and Project B (i.e add them to your Setup.exe as Resources)
- Then you need to implement the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96732/embedding-one-dll-inside-another-as-an-embedded-resource-and-then-calling-it-fro)

Comment: Would you please tell me more about embedded resource?

Comment: I do the roght click on DLL and choose properties , It shows me `full name , full path, custom tool...`

Comment: @AmitPal Check edited answer, basically you add the dlls as if you are adding an image or some other resources