# How do I bake dependencies into C# console program?

Tags: c#, dependencies, socket.io, socketio4net

I have a `C#` console program that uses the `nuget` plugin `SocketIO4Net`

When I build the `exe` and move it to my Windows 2008 server, it doesn't work, whereas on my local machine, it works.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'SocketIOClient, Version=0.6.26.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Is there any way I can bake all my dependencies into the `exe`?

---

I tried doing:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
{
    var resName = "converter.SocketIOClient.dll";
    var thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    using (var input = thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resName))
    {
        return input != null
             ? Assembly.Load(StreamToBytes(input))
             : null;
    }
};
```

But that didn't work. Perhaps I'm getting the `resourceName` wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my example which is based off of [Embedding one dll inside another as an embedded resource and then calling it from my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96732/embedding-one-dll-inside-another-as-an-embedded-resource-and-then-calling-it-fro) but has some helpful screenshots.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MyEmbbedFile;

namespace ProjectNameSpace
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
            {
                var resName = "ProjectNameSpace.MyEmbbedFile.dll";
                var thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                using (var input = thisAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resName))
                {
                    return input != null
                         ? Assembly.Load(StreamToBytes(input))
                         : null;
                }
            };
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            MyEmbbedFileApp app = new MyEmbbedFileApp();
            app.DoStuff();
        }

        private static byte[] StreamToBytes(Stream input)
        {
            var capacity = input.CanSeek ? (int)input.Length : 0;
            using (var output = new MemoryStream(capacity))
            {
                int readLength;
                var buffer = new byte[4096];

                do
                {
                    readLength = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    output.Write(buffer, 0, readLength);
                }
                while (readLength != 0);

                return output.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are 2 other things you will need to do:

You will still need to make sure you add your assembly as a reference so your code compiles. Just make sure it does not copy to the output directory.

[image]

The second thing you need to do is add your reference to the project as a normal file. Then set it's build action to Embedded Resource under properties.

[image]

Comment: Following those steps inflated the filesize of my .exe, but I still get the same error

Comment: I got it to work. I just had to add the dependencies that my dependency depended on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Use [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) to 'hydrate' embedded assemblies at runtime.

This project [SQLDiagCmd](https://github.com/Mitch-Wheat/SQLDiagCmd) at Github contains an example of doing this. It is based on [Jeffrey Ricther's method](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx?Redirected=true):

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) => 
{ 

   String resourceName = "AssemblyLoadingAndReflection." + 
                          new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll"; 

   using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                               .GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))   
   { 
      Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length]; 
      stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length); 
      return Assembly.Load(assemblyData); 
   } 
};
```

The 'trick' is where the embedded assembly is located and (as you have found), the string used to refer to it in the `AssemblyResolve` handler. [I don't have time right now but will look again later...]

Comment: I tried doing your example, but with `resourceName` substituted with the name of my missing .dll, or so I thought. I edited my question with my implementation

Comment: have you looked at the github example?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure what I'm missing.