# Put a dll inside a dll in C#

Tags: c#, dll, module

I'm trying to make a C# dll that includes all its dependencies in itself. So that the dll, which is actaully a module for another C# program, can be only one file. So is there a way to put a dll inside a dll and then make add a reference to this dll?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedding one dll inside another as an embedded resource and then calling it from my code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96732/embedding-one-dll-inside-another-as-an-embedded-resource-and-then-calling-it-fro)

Comment: thx (mandatory chars...)

Comment: An alternative approach is to use ILMerge. It creates one dll from a set of assemblies and can be applied to about any application without code changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedding as a resource and ILMerge was already mentioned in the comments. I'd like to give another alternative: [ILRepack](https://github.com/gluck/il-repack). It works like ILMerge but unlike ILMerge is still actively developed.