# How can I build my c# class library along with the reference?

Tags: c#, dll

I'm creating a basic class library that heavily wraps another DLL reference. I'm trying to build a DLL but it seems to not include the reference.

Is there a way I can build and package the my entire solution in a DLL along with the reference DLL?

Comment: I assume you mean it isn't including the referenced assembly in the project output directory. Specify "Copy Local: True" in the reference properties in Visual Studio.

Comment: Do you want to embed the third party DLL in your DLL, or simply copy it to the output? Copying it to the output is as simple as ticking 'Copy Local' in the property panel of the references. For embedding, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable)

Comment: Do you mean something specific when you say - `heavily wraps another DLL reference`? I believe you have a class library C# project in which you are referencing another *.dll file and trying to build the project from Visual Studio. Are you?

Comment: for embedding see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96732/embedding-one-dll-inside-another-as-an-embedded-resource-and-then-calling-it-fro

Comment: Yes. Basically the main app is a Java App. I use IKVM to convert that to a DLL and import that as a reference. I need to then create a C# Class Library that wraps that DLL.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I use ilmerge by microsoft (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630) to merge my DLLs into a single DLL file.

Just go thru the following and you'll have the merged DLL.

Step 1: Install ilmerge and put it on your system classpath
Step 2:

```
ilmerge /out:MergedDLLName.dll /closed DLL1.dll DLL2.dll DLL3.dll
```

Hope this helps.