# Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies in library project

Tags: c#

I saw a lot of topic about this error (especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies)). But i'm unable to correct this error.

I have a solution C# WPF that I manage with visual studio 2017. My main project use a second one project. The second one project use a DLL, stored in a folder. Something like this :

[image]

`MyClass` use classes contained in MyDll (added in References as Embeded ressource, with dllNamspace). In `MyClass` I have :

```
public MyClass()
{
    dllNamspace.DllClass item = new dllNamspace.DllClass();
}
```

When I got to definition for `DllClass`, it's ok. I can see all functions/methods. But when I run MainProject, I have an Exception :

> The type initializer for 'MyClass' threw an exception

With InnerException

> Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies 'dllNamspace'

I've try to reload MyDll, rebuild all, add reference in MainProject, copy dll in bin folder. I always have this exception.

Comment: Right click on the properties and see from where this dll is being referenced. Also try a clean and build of your whole solution

Comment: Do you have fusion logs enabled?

Comment: Does your `MyDLL` need other Dlls? Are they in your Debug Folder?

Comment: @KingoftheNorth you mean properties for the file or the project ? In already cleaned and rebuild all the solution but I have the error.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I don't know if `MyDLL` needs other. How can I do ?

Comment: Did you write it yourself? If not, which one is is it? Do you have a source? Did the source not mention any dependencies?

Comment: Why an embedded resource? Try just setting its build action as copy to output so it can be found.

Comment: @A.Pissicat: i meant the properties of the dll, sorry. There should be a link to a log file containing the build details and error.

Comment: @KingoftheNorth properties does not help me. There is just the file name and build action

Comment: Since you are embedding one assembly(dll) in another then have look at this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96732/embedding-one-dll-inside-another-as-an-embedded-resource-and-then-calling-it-fro

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer the dll has been writer by a coworker. Unfortunately there is no documentation for this. But in the reference, I can see the dll in Object Browser.

Comment: @A.Pissicat Then you are either targeting a different .Net version as the dll or the MyDLL needs another dll that you don't have.